# Is Javascript an Effective Method of Creating Fluid Layouts?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like opinions on whether or not Javascript is a still a viable and relatively effective method of producing fluid website layouts.  **I know that it is possible** to create fluid layouts with Javascript, but relative to other methods (e.g. CSS3/HTML5) how does it stand up in terms of performance and complexity?  The function below represents what I mean.  In the function, javascript is being used to find the dimensions of various elements and place other elements accordingly.  To see it working, [follow this link](http://www.injuredpets.org/returnForm).

```js
function onPageResize() {
  //center the header
  var headerWidth = document.getElementById('header').offsetWidth; //find the width of the div 'header'
  var insideHeaderWidth = (document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].offsetWidth + document.getElementsByClassName('header')[1].offsetWidth + document.getElementById('logoHeader').offsetWidth); //find the combined width of all elements located within the parent element 'header'
  document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style.marginLeft = ((headerWidth - insideHeaderWidth) / 2) + "px"; //set the margin-left of the first element inside of the 'header' div
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //justify alignment of textboxes
  var subtitleWidth = document.getElementsByClassName('subtitle'); //assign the properties of all elements in the class 'subtitle' to a new array 'subtitleWidth'
  var inputForm = document.getElementsByClassName('inputForm'); //assign the properties of all elements in the class 'inputForm' to a new array 'inputForm'
  for (i = 0; i < inputForm.length; i++) { //for every element in the array 'inputForm' set the margin-left to dynamically place the input forms relative to eachother
    inputForm[i].style.marginLeft = (subtitleWidth[4].offsetWidth - subtitleWidth[i].offsetWidth) + "px";
  }
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //place footer on absolute bottom of page
  if (window.innerHeight >= 910) { //when the page is larger than '910px' execute the following
    var totalHeight = 0; //initialize a new variable 'totalHeight' which will eventually be used to calulate the total height of all elements in the window
    var bodyBlockHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('bodyBlock'); //assign the properties of all elements in the class 'bodyBlock' to a new array 'bodyBlockHeight'
    for (i = 0; i < bodyBlockHeight.length; i++) { //for every instance of bodyBlockHeight in the array, add the height of that element into the 'totalHeight'
      totalHeight += bodyBlockHeight[i].offsetHeight;
    }
    totalHeight += document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight; //finally, to add the height of the only element that has yet to be quantified, include the height of the element 'header' into the 'totalHeight'

    /*Set the margin-top of the element 'footer' to the result of subtracting the combined heights of all elements in the window from the height of the window.
    This will cause the footer to always be at the absolute bottom of the page, despite whether or not content actually exists there. */
    document.getElementById('footer').style.marginTop = (window.innerHeight - totalHeight) - document.getElementById('footer').offsetHeight + "px";
  } else {
    //if the page height is larger than 910px (approx the height of all elements combined), then simply place the footer 20px below the last element in the body
    document.getElementById('footer').style.marginTop = "20px"
  }
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}
```

Again, the result of the above function can be viewed [at this link](http://www.injuredpets.org/returnForm).

Thank you to any and all who offer their opinions!

Comment: I personally would use CSS3 to create a relatively fluid layout and then add CSS media queries to make it truly 'fluid', much easier, cleaner, more mantainable, browser efficient etc etc than JavaScript. Also if the user has no JS then the layout is screwed.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but I have seen some bootstrap templates with ridiculous amounts of @media queries to account for all possible screen dimensions...

Comment: Well it's however complicated you need it to be really. Bootstrap will because it's a CSS framework, however you will hardly use any of them. I'd say use your custom CSS and slowly build it up, first with standard CSS using percentages and max widths/ min widths, then slowly add media queries when it breaks.

Comment: Use css to create this - it's what it's for - in javascript this is more complicated and way less performant than css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using CSS rather than JavaScript because that is what CSS is designed to do. If you want a fluid layout play around with using percentage widths, floats and media queries.